# XSLT select multiple items

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<History>
    <Release Date="20170927" Version="2">
        <Item Type="">Element 2.0</Item>
        <Item Type="">Element 2.1</Item>
        <Item>Element 2.2</Item>
        <Item Type="Remark">REMARK!</Item>
    </Release>
    <Release Date="20170925" Version="1">
        <Item Type="">Element 1.0</Item>
        <Item Type="">Element 1.1</Item>
        <Item>Element 1.2</Item>
        <Item Type="Remark">REMARK!</Item>
    </Release>
</History>
```

There are Item, Item Type="" and Item Type="Remark".

I need to display Item and Item Type="" in the same column, but NOT Item Type="Remark". The XML structure is given, I can only change the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

     <xsl:for-each select="History/Release/Item[@Type!='Remark']">
       <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
     </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My current output with this XSLT is

```
Element 2.0
Element 2.1
Element 1.0
Element 1.1
```

where Element 2.2 and 1.2 (from the  elements) are missing.

So, how do I fix the XSLT to get  as well as the  elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:for-each select="History/Release/Item[@Type!='Remark' or not(@Type)]">
```

Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="History/Release/Item[@Type!='Remark']">
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the xslt with conditional expression:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">

     <xsl:for-each select="History/Release/Item[not(@Type)] | History/Release/Item[@Type!='Remark']">
       <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/><br />
     </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works great as well, thank you! 
I have accepted Rupesh answer as it is shorter.